# Detect hardware damage with software?

Tags: laptop, overheating

I brought my laptop to school this morning. Just as our teacher went inside the classroom, I swiftly shoved it in the laptop bag. Unfortunately, I forgot to shut it down properly and it wasn't even in sleep mode. So it was running idle inside the bag. An hour later I noticed the bag was hot so I checked the laptop and found it automatically shut down due to overheating. It was really hot and there was the smell of burning metal and plastic.

I am afraid that some chips got burned in the process. However, I wouldn't risk opening the laptop as I might not be able to re-assemble it.

How can I detect any hardware problems with software? And is there a risk of data loss due to an overheated storage device?

Comment: wy you not open the laptop and start. He will not start if the chip is damaged.

Comment: It is working fine, for now. What I am afraid of are minor damages that can mean a lot in particular situations like errors on some I/O operations...

Comment: Wiki is correct; just because it starts up at all does not mean there are not other problems that are intermittent or not manifest until specific circumstances.

Comment: Could it it just be the bag getting heated up causing the smell. I *have* had this before. Generally computers shut down before real damage happens.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Good point. Actually the smell resembles the odor of burnt hair / cloth(ing).

Comment: Its not an answer - ultrasawblade suggested *everything* i'd try, but i'm guessing its just the bag ;p

Answer (score 2):

As @RedGrittyBrick says, while the laptop is working I would back up any important data on it.

If it seems to be working normally there may not be much you can do besides use it until a tangible problem develops and then exchange it under any warranty that may be provided.  Depending on how you are with people you might get the manufacturer to exchange it anyway.

There are some things you can do to test for hardware issues:

- Many BIOSes have a built-in diagnostic test that you can use.
- You can test your memory with a [Memtest86](http://www.memtest86.com/) boot disk.
- [Prime95](http://files.extremeoverclocking.com/file.php?f=103) can test your CPU and see if your system will remain stable under load.
- [SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) is great for getting and understanding your hard drive's SMART parameters.
- Things like [FurMark 3d](http://www.ozone3d.net/benchmarks/fur/) can stress your GPU and see if your GPU will remain stable under load.

You also should at least take the back of the laptop off, if it is possible, and look without fully disassembling to see if there is any obvious damage.  Take it to a repair shop if you are really worried about it.

Comment: +1 for memtest 86 and prime95.  I'd add checking SMART at least, `wmic diskdrive get status` from command line, unless it has an SSD, heck do it either way.  Any recent Dell computer has an excellent set of diagnostics in their BIOS

Answer (score -2):

Unknown Device Identifier Software is a software to detect hardware that does not work due to driver problems, With this software you can find out what the hardware does not have a driver and the type / version of software you should look Please download the Unknown Device Identifier on the internet only to download it's really

I think the risk is too hot if the data will be lost due to hard drive.

Here are 5 Ways to Overcome Computer Too Hot 1. Routine maintenance 2. upgrade the power supply 3.setting your hard drive number 4. reduce the program running 5. added an additional fan in the rear casing